# Having a hard time getting an expression into the desired form

Tags: algebra-precalculus

> My goal is to obtain the following:
>   $$
> g(0)=\frac{B}{1-2p}-\frac{A+B}{1-2p}\frac{r^B-1}{r^{A+B}-1}.
> $$

This is what I know:
$$
g(A)=g(B)=0, \ g(k)=a+br^k+\frac{k}{1-2p}, \ a \text{ and } b \text{ constants}.
$$

This is the work I have done:
$$
0=a+br^A+\frac{A}{1-2p}=a+br^B+\frac{B}{1-2p},
$$
subtracting the second equation from the first equation I get
$$
0=b(r^A-r^B)+\frac{A-B}{1-2p}, \text{ so } b=\frac{A-B}{1-2p}\frac{1}{r^B-r^A}.
$$
Plugging this value for $b$ back into $g(A)$ gives:
$$
0=a+\frac{A-B}{1-2p}\frac{r^A}{r^B-r^A}+\frac{A}{1-2p}, \text{ so } a = \frac{B-A}{1-2p}\frac{r^A}{r^B-r^A}-\frac{A}{1-2p}.
$$

Plugging these values for $a$ and $b$ into $g(0)$ this is what I get
$$
g(0)=\frac{B-A}{1-2p}\frac{r^A}{r^B-r^A}-\frac{A}{1-2p}+\frac{A-B}{1-2p}\frac{1}{r^B-r^A}
$$
$$
=\frac{B-A}{1-2p}\frac{r^A}{r^B-r^A}-\frac{A}{1-2p}-\frac{B-A}{1-2p}\frac{1}{r^B-r^A}=\frac{(B-A)(r^A-1)}{(1-2p)(r^B-r^A)}-\frac{A}{1-2p}.
$$

I get stuck at this point. I can't think of anything else to get me from where I am at to what I want $g(0)$ to equal. I appreciate any help.